# Bash completion scripting - getting a "transparent proxy"-like behaviour

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

I am trying to write a simple Bash completion script for a program that runs its arguments as a command. A good example of this is kind of program is the `prime-run` script provided by the `nvidia-prime` package:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia "$@"
```

This script sets a few environment variables, which instructs the prime driver to use the Nvidia dGPU on a hybrid system. The first argument is treated as the command, and all trailing arguments are passed through. So for example you can run `prime-run code .` and VSCode will start in the current directory using the dGPU.

Therefore from a completion-script POV, what we want is to basically try to complete as if the `prime-run` token isn't there (hence "transparent proxy"-like behaviour). To give a rather contrived example:

```
> prime-run journalc<TAB>
(completes journalctl)
> prime-run journalctl --us<TAB>
(completes --user)
```

However I am finding this surprisingly difficult in Bash (not that I know how in other shells). So the question is simple: is it possible and if so how?

#### Ideas I've (hopelessly) had

- The simple `complete -A command prime-run`: the first argument gets completed as a command as expected (let's call it `foo`), but the following arguments are also completed as commands rather than as arguments to `foo`
- Use some combination of `compgen` and `complete -p` to invoke the completion function of `foo`, but AFAIK the completion function for all `foo` is locally defined and thus uncallable

Comment: i'd go like this: first, type the `foo ...args...` command as usual so you can take advantage of any available completion rules, then, move cursor to the left most and add `prime-run`.

Comment: @pynexj yep that's what I currently have to do. `foo args`, then `ctrl+A` to go to start of line, then type `prime-run`. It's not that difficult but do it a dozen times everyday and it becomes an annoying chore. (p.s. `prime-run` is just an example here of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

`bash-completion` provides a function named `_command_offset` ([permalink](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/6f1bbda3c66814befa8025d49363b4070ef20008/bash_completion#L2119-L2123)), which is exactly what I need.

```sh
# A meta-command completion function for commands like sudo(8), which need to
# first complete on a command, then complete according to that command's own
# completion definition.
```

Keep reading if you are interested in how I got here.

---

So I was daydreaming the other day, when it hit me - doesn't `sudo` basically have the exact same behaviour I want? So the task became simple - reverse engineer the completion script for `sudo`. Source available here: [permalink](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/6f1bbda3c66814befa8025d49363b4070ef20008/completions/sudo).

Turns out, most of the code has to do with completing the various options, so it's safe to simply throw most of it out:

- L 8-11, 50-52: Related to `sudo`'s edit mode. Safe to ditch.
- L 19-24, 27-39, 43-49: These complete `sudo`'s options. Safe to ditch.

So we're left with this:

```sh
_sudo()
{
    local cur prev words cword split
    _init_completion -s || return

    for ((i = 1; i <= cword; i++)); do
        if [[ ${words[i]} != -* ]]; then
            local PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
            local root_command=${words[i]}
            _command_offset $i
            return
        fi
    done

    $split && return
} &&
    complete -F _sudo sudo sudoedit
```

- The `for` and `if` block are there to deal with `sudo`'s options that precede the "guest command". Safe to ditch (after replacing all `$i` with `1`).
- The variable `$split` is only referenced in `_init_completion` ([permalink](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/6f1bbda3c66814befa8025d49363b4070ef20008/bash_completion#L966)), and it seems to be used for handling different argument styles (`--foo=bar` v.s. `--foo bar`). Same with the `-s` flag. Irrelevant.
- Appending to `$PATH` and setting `$root_command` have to do with privilege escalation. Only relevant to `sudo`.

So after the dust has cleared, by process of elimination, I ended up with this simple chunk of code:

```sh
_my-script()
{
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

    _command_offset 1

} && complete -F _my-script my-script
```

Declaring these four local variables and calling `_init_completion` is standard for all completion scipts, so really it's as simple as one command. Of course someone had to write the massively-complex `_command_offset` function so lucky me I guess?

Anyways, thank you for reading the story of me messing around and hopefully this will be helpful to some other person in the future.